# Pass value to textbox in website using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to navigate a website and perform activities based on input from Excel.

I am stuck in passing values to input element which auto populates value in next text box based on value we have passed (eg: if I pass a zip code in target box then city name is auto populated in next box). I can pass values but it is not triggering the JS which auto populates value.

Target box code in webpage

```
<input name="zipcode" class="inputBoxRequired" id="zipcode"     onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onblur="getZipCity(this.value,'/ProviderPortal')" type="text" size="46" maxlength="5">
```

Code tried

```
Set Zip = ie_Doc.getElementById("zipcode")
 Zip.Value = Zip_Code 'Here value gets updated but associated js is not triggered
 ie_Doc.getElementById("zipcode").Focus
```

even tried fire event

```
Zip.FireEvent ("onchange")
```

In webpage it is mentioned as Onkeypress event. I googled to find solution but I can't get exact one.

Comment: Can you share the URL please?

Comment: sorry @QHarr  its an secure web portal I am not able to share the URL , need to sign in to view the page I am taking about.

Comment: Did you fire the onBlur as well? And for some of these things they expect key press that are best mimicked by .Focus first then .Sendkeys "Text"..... dreaded as sendkeys are.

Comment: how should I do it please suggest

Comment: Zip.FireEvent ("onkeypress") :  Zip.FireEvent ("onblur")

Comment: If I used sendkeys, yes its worked for me but I don't want to use sendkeys to perform this activity, is there is any robust method to achieve this like we are changing value in drop down using fireevent.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr using  Zip.FireEvent ("onblur") its get activate, thank you so much again.

Answer (score 4):

```
Zip.FireEvent ("onkeypress")
Zip.FireEvent ("onblur")  '<== Apparently this did the trick
```

Those are the shown events.

Comment: Why doesn't this answer get the same upvotes as the question recieved? Nice finding again @QHarr.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same scenario for solution verified this post whereas in my case I do not have "onblur" tag, so I did some search and come up with an solution.

```
Dim event_onChange As Object
Set event_onChange = ie_Doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
event_onChange.initEvent "keypress", True, False
Zip.dispatchEvent event_onChange
```

It will help others who are facing same problem.